# H2 Database : how unlock a database file for backup copy?

Tags: backup, h2, lockfile

I'm using h2database version 1.4.200 with hibernate for saving in database file.

My programs needs to regulary save backup and I don't care about corruption's file's problems.

After looking the documentation : http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_file_locking

I decided to use parameter LOCK_FILE=NO. I saved my models and keeped the entity manager opened. When I tryed to copy the db file "data.mv.db", my database file was always locked even if I used Lock_FILE=NO.

Parameter LOCK_FILE=NO, does it work correctly ?
There is a alternative for copying speedly my db-file in java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attempt to copy the file when database is in use is a way to get a possibly corrupted backup.

H2 has [BACKUP](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#backup) command for online backups.

```sql
BACKUP TO 'filename.zip'
```

This command creates a ZIP archive with a consistent copy of the database file.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem.
For information :
`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("BACKUP TO 'backup.zip'");
conn.close();`